# JUNG: Saving graph into image file

Tags: java, image, swing, jung

I use JUNG to visualize my graph / network.
Now i want to save the graph (as seen in the VisualizationViewer) in a image file. I use the paint() / paintAll() function of the VisualizationViewer (who extend JPanel). But with this function, only the part who is actually shown in the VisualizationViewer (for example after zooming in) is in the image. I want to draw all Vertexes and Edges. Is there a way to draw all Elements?

Comment: Have you checked the following SO post? [Exporting JUNG graphs to hi-res images (preferably vector based)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518390/exporting-jung-graphs-to-hi-res-images-preferably-vector-based)

Comment: Dont help, because he will save save only the part shown in the vv, e.g. after zoom in/out.For Vector based output i use Batik.

Comment: Who is "he" you are referring to? How about the rest of the solutions for the given post?

Comment: I can save the part of the graph i see as PNG and SVG, that is no problem. The problem is, that i want so save the whole graph not only a part of it. And this problem is not part of the solution in the given post. In the meantime i think it exist no "simple" solution. I need to write my own functions.

Comment: There is a sample source code `VisualizationImageServerDemo` from **jung-samples-2.0.1.jar** which uses `VisualizationImageServer` class to save the graph at a defined size and position: `Image im = vv.getImage(new Point2d.Double(300,300), new Dimension(600,600));`

Comment: I know this example. Here the problem is, that VisualizationImageServer dont support all methodes i use with VisualizationViewer (like all renderer). So i can't replace my VisualizationViewer with VisualizationImageServer. But i will look at the getImage() function, maybe there is my solution.

Comment: Facing the same problem, did you come up with a solution @Thargor?

Comment: @Zakum i stoped working years ago on that project. but as i remeber, i found no solution.

Comment: @Thargor Oh, I forgot all about this, too. Managed to make it work using the freehp.hraphicsIO library: http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/
I'll post the solution below for posteriority.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using the [freeHEP library](http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/) and JUNG's `VisualizationImageServer`:

```
private void doSaveAs() throws IOException {
    // instantiate and configure image-able visualization viewer
    VisualizationImageServer<Vertex, Edge> vis =
            new VisualizationImageServer<Vertex, Edge>(this.visViewer.getGraphLayout(),
                                                       this.visViewer.getGraphLayout().getSize());

    setUpAppearance(vis);

    ExportDialog export = new ExportDialog();
    export.showExportDialog(vis, "Export view as ...", vis, "export");
}
```

When called, this will open an export dialog to the user, where directory and filetype can be selected.

In this snippet, ExportDialog is  `org.freehep.graphicsbase.util.export.ExportDialog`, which you would have to somehow get to your build path, in my case using maven by adding `freehep-graphicsio` to my pom file.

The field `this.visViewer` contains your regular `VisualizationViewer` instance, that you would also use for displaying your graph.

The method `setUpAppearance(vis);` performs the same setup that I do on the `VisualizationViewer` instance for displaying purposes. Here's an example, the details will probably vary for you:

```
private void setUpAppearance(BasicVisualizationServer<Vertex, Edge> vis) {
    vis.setBackground(BGCOLOR);
    vis.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1500, 600)); // Sets the viewing area

    // modify vertices
    vis.getRenderContext().setVertexLabelTransformer(new ToStringLabeller());
    vis.getRenderContext().setVertexFontTransformer(Transformers.vertexFontTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setVertexShapeTransformer(Transformers.vertexShapeTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setVertexFillPaintTransformer(Transformers.vertexFillPaintTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setVertexDrawPaintTransformer(Transformers.vertexDrawPaintTransformer);
    vis.getRenderer().getVertexLabelRenderer().setPosition(Position.CNTR);

    // modify edges
    vis.getRenderContext().setEdgeShapeTransformer(Transformers.edgeShapeTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setEdgeDrawPaintTransformer(Transformers.edgeDrawPaintTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setArrowDrawPaintTransformer(Transformers.edgeDrawPaintTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setArrowFillPaintTransformer(Transformers.edgeDrawPaintTransformer);
    vis.getRenderContext().setEdgeArrowPredicate(Transformers.edgeArrowPredicate);
    vis.getRenderContext().setEdgeStrokeTransformer(Transformers.edgeStrokeHighlightingTransformer);
}
```

As a last step you need to figure out when `doSaveAs` should be called. For instance you could add a Button on the UI for that.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about JUNG, but it is just extends a JPanel to do the painting then you should be able to use the [Screen Image](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/13/screen-image/) class to create an image of any component.

Comment: Dont work. VisualizationViewer is a Element to visualize a network / graph. If in zoom into the graph i see only a part of it and all Methodes save only these part into the Image.