# Output a JUNG visualisation to PDF using iText

Tags: networking, pdf, visualization, itext, jung

I'm trying to output a JUNG network to a PDF using the iText library.

Many solutions seem to display the graph in a frame before using a library to capture the screen and output this to some format such as EPS. However, my application will automatically build many networks and output them so displaying each network on the screen before saving to a file is not a great solution.

I've done some searching and not come across exactly what I'm doing. It seems straightforward to output the graph to a PNG (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420779/jung-save-whole-graph-not-only-visible-part-as-image/10426669#10426669)) but the quality of a PNG is not suitable for my needs.

My current code is below and is based on writing charts from JFreeChart to PDF (see [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2010/02/generate-pie-chart-bar-graph-in-pdf-using-itext-jfreechart.html)). I'm trying to get a Graphics2D object that I can "draw" the graph onto and then output to PDF. This code generates a null pointer exception as the graphics object returned from visualise.getGraphics() is null.

Any advice, code snippets or online examples would be appreciated.

```
public void write() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    // Open the PDF file for writing
    this.document = new Document();
    this.writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(this.document, new FileOutputStream(this.fileName));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    //Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(WIDTH, HEIGHT, new DefaultFontMapper());

    // Apply a layout to the graph
    Layout<Vertex, Edge> layout = new CircleLayout<Vertex, Edge>(this.network);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));

    // Draw on the graphics 2D object
    VisualizationImageServer<Vertex, Edge> visualise = new VisualizationImageServer<Vertex, Edge>(layout, new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    visualise.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(WIDTH + 50, HEIGHT + 50));
    visualise.setDoubleBuffered(false);
    Graphics2D graphics2d = (Graphics2D) visualise.getGraphics();
    visualise.paintComponents(graphics2d);

    graphics2d.dispose();
    contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);

    this.document.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by Joshua is correct. I guess I would have never searched for headless!

I had to modify the code at http://sourceforge.net/projects/jung/forums/forum/252062/topic/1407188 slightly as I found that creating the Graphics2D object from a BufferedImage is not suitable. Instead the Graphics2D should be made from a PDFTemplate. For future reference I've posted my working code.

```
public void write() throws IOException, DocumentException {

    // Open the PDF file for writing - and create a Graphics2D object
    this.document = new Document();
    this.writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(this.document, new FileOutputStream(this.fileName));
    document.open();
    PdfContentByte contentByte = writer.getDirectContent();
    PdfTemplate template = contentByte.createTemplate(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    Graphics2D graphics2d = template.createGraphics(WIDTH, HEIGHT, new DefaultFontMapper());

    // Apply a layout to the graph
    Layout<Vertex, Edge> layout = new CircleLayout<Vertex, Edge>(this.network);
    layout.setSize(new Dimension(WIDTH / 2, HEIGHT / 2));

    // Create a visualisation object - set background color etc
    VisualizationViewer<Vertex, Edge> visualise = new VisualizationViewer<Vertex, Edge>(layout, new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
    visualise.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    visualise.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

    // Create a container to hold the visualisation
    Container container = new Container();
    container.addNotify();
    container.add(visualise);
    container.setVisible(true);
    container.paintComponents(graphics2d);

    // Dispose of the graphics and close the document
    graphics2d.dispose();
    contentByte.addTemplate(template, 0, 0);
    this.document.close();

}
```