# How can I visualize my graph from JUNG in an image?

Tags: jung

I've just started using JUNG for creating and showing graphs.I;ve seen various examples of visualizing graphs for example in JFrames.Is it possible that instead of a JFrame I'm able to visualize my graph in an image? like .jpg or postScript etc?

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10420779/jung-save-whole-graph-not-only-visible-part-as-image/10426669#10426669

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/)?
In my project, I use GrpahViz to render beautiful graphs and JUNG as some sort of fast and cheap live view of the current 'under construction' graph.

Comment: I've tried GraphViz but it doesn't provide me a certain thing that JUNG does.In GraphViz I'm not able to explicit plot a node in a certain coordinate.That's why I'm now considering JUNG