# Mysterious NullPointerException in an applet using FreeHep library

Tags: java, graphics, applet, freehep

I have an applet that visualizes a large graph using JUNG2. [A while back I managed to add an export feature which allows the user to export the graphs to vector-based images](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8559977/328725), this time utilizing [FreeHEP library](http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/). It all worked nice and smooth (I even used PDF exports in a publication).

Now the applet seems to crash when I try to export the graphs. Digging into the java console I found out that it's due a NPE deep down in the library. Below is the relevant portion of the  stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-2" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.freehep.graphicsio.gif.GIFImageWriteParam.<init>(GIFImageWriteParam.java:28)
    at org.freehep.graphicsio.gif.GIFImageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam(GIFImageWriter.java:73)
    at org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.ImageExportFileType.<init>(ImageExportFileType.java:71)
    at org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.ImageIOExportFileType.onRegistration(ImageIOExportFileType.java:50)
    at javax.imageio.spi.SubRegistry.registerServiceProvider(ServiceRegistry.java:715)
    at javax.imageio.spi.ServiceRegistry.registerServiceProvider(ServiceRegistry.java:302)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportFileTypeRegistry.addApplicationClasspathExportFileTypes(ExportFileTypeRegistry.java:122)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportFileTypeRegistry.getDefaultInstance(ExportFileTypeRegistry.java:50)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportFileType.getExportFileTypes(ExportFileType.java:181)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportFileType.getExportFileTypes(ExportFileType.java:173)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportDialog.addAllExportFileTypes(ExportDialog.java:64)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportDialog.<init>(ExportDialog.java:130)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportDialog.<init>(ExportDialog.java:90)
    at org.freehep.util.export.ExportDialog.<init>(ExportDialog.java:82)
    at myproject.visualization.ExtendedModelGraphMouse$ExportActionListener.actionPerformed(ExtendedModelGraphMouse.java:167)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    ...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.freehep.graphics2d.PixelGraphics2D.<clinit>(PixelGraphics2D.java:101)
    ... 53 more
```

---

I have been digging into the [source code of the FreeHEP library](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.freehep/freehep-graphicsio/2.1.2/org/freehep/graphicsio/gif/GIFImageWriteParam.java#GIFImageWriteParam) (hosted at Grep Code), the last line (topmost) in the stack trace points to the line that starts with `UserProperties`

```
public GIFImageWriteParam(Locale locale) {
    super(locale);
    canWriteProgressive = true;
    progressiveMode = MODE_DEFAULT;

    UserProperties def = new UserProperties(GIFGraphics2D
            .getDefaultProperties());
    quantizeColors = def.isProperty(GIFGraphics2D.QUANTIZE_COLORS);
    quantizeMode = def.getProperty(GIFGraphics2D.QUANTIZE_MODE);
}
```

From what I can decipher this should mean that `GIFGraphics2D` turns out to be `null` - why, I don't understand. I have double checked my build file to make sure necessary libs are in place, and neither my build file nor my code that utilizes the [`ExportDialog`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.freehep/freehep-graphics-base/2.1.2/org/freehep/util/export/ExportDialog.java#ExportDialog) (see the very first link in the question body) has changed in over a year. So what could be the issue here?

Comment: Does it give a `caused by` anywhere in the trace?

Comment: Is that the full stacktrace or... ?

Comment: No this it not the full trace, it's pretty long. I must have forgotten that, sorry... I just added the "caused by" bit

Answer (score 2):

Freehep is using an unpublished internal java SDK method. And the implementation of this method changed with java version 1.7. You probably upgraded your JDK/JRE to the latest java release.

Fortunately this has been fixed in the github repository of freehep (I could not find a freehep release after 2010, but it is being developed and available on github and maven).

The issue in github can be found [here](https://github.com/freehep/freehep-vectorgraphics/issues/6).

A bug-report with some information on the [Oracle Site](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7073211).

So update your freehep installation from github, rebuild it, and use the new libraries.

Answer (score 1):

I am a novice with github, Maven, etc. So please forgive me if the following is either trivial or unclear.

Despite using the github version of freehep-vectorgraphics (version 2.2.2), I still get this error message when running my code:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.freehep.graphicsio.gif.GIFImageWriteParam.<init>(GIFImageWriteParam.java:28)
at org.freehep.graphicsio.gif.GIFImageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam(GIFImageWriter.java:73)
at org.freehep.graphicsio.exportchooser.ImageExportFileType.<init>(ImageExportFileType.java:71)
at org.freehep.graphicsio.gif.GIFExportFileType.<init>(GIFExportFileType.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
```

Line 28 of GIFImageWriteParam.java looks like this:

```
UserProperties def = new UserProperties(GIFGraphics2D.getDefaultProperties());
```

According to Mark Donszelmann on github, the error is due to a bug in PixelGraphics2D. The patch he suggested contains the variable 'clazz'. Here's the section from PixelGraphics2D where this variable appears. It looks very different from the text of the patch:

```
Class<?> clazz = Class.forName("sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment");
displayX11 = true;
Method method = clazz.getMethod("isDisplayLocal");
if (Modifier.isStatic(method.getModifiers())) {
        // JDK 1.6
        displayLocal = (Boolean) method.invoke(null);
} else {
        try {
                // since JDK 1.7
                displayLocal = (Boolean)method.invoke(clazz.newInstance());
        } catch (InstantiationException  e) {
        }
}
```

Any idea how I can fix this problem?