# JUNG Export editable Graph in a VisualizationViewer into an image

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have an editable VisualizationViewer inside a GraphZoomScrollPane. After moving and reorganizing the graph I want to save the edited version into a image file.

When I tried using VisualizationImageServer it requires the layout which removes the modifications and set up the nodes to the original layout.

By printing the JPanel into the image, I only get the visible portion and I need the full image to be saved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expert on Jung, but this question seems to provide a workable approach to what you want to do:

[Exporting JUNG graphs to hi-res images (preferably vector based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518390/exporting-jung-graphs-to-hi-res-images-preferably-vector-based)