# Java automization of Export HQ Images to pdf

Tags: java, image, user-interface, jung2

I want to get high quality images of my network created in Jung. ExportDialog of the FreeHEP VectorGraphics library gives this option in the form of a dialog box.

```
ExportDialog export = new ExportDialog();
export.showExportDialog(vv, "Export view as ...", vv, "export");
```

Where *vv* is the VisualizationViewer that I want to print out. I want to avoid choosing the file type and location everytime and automize the export so that the file is automatically saved to a folder as a pdf file. So I wrote the following code but it does not generate the picture that I want.

```
  Properties p = new Properties();
  p.setProperty("PageSize","A4");
  VectorGraphics g = new PSGraphics2D(new File("Output.pdf"),vv.getSize()); 
  g.setProperties(p);
  g.startExport(); 
  vv.print(g); 
  g.endExport();
```

Related links : [Exporting JUNG graphs to hi-res images (preferably vector based)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8518390/exporting-jung-graphs-to-hi-res-images-preferably-vector-based/8559977#8559977) and http://java.freehep.org/vectorgraphics/Manual.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To export pdf files:

```
 VectorGraphics g = new PDFGraphics2D(new File("ResultImages/Output.pdf"), vv);
```